# RSA SSA PSS & PKCS7 test vectors with SHA 256

Tags: rsa, digital-signature

Can someone share the test vectors for RSA SSA PSS & V1.5 PKCS7 with SHA 256 algorithm along with salt length?

Comment: https://csrc.nist.gov/Projects/Cryptographic-Algorithm-Validation-Program/Component-Testing#RSASigGenPrim would normally be my answer, but they only test RSASP1, so the PKCS1 and PSS parts are already done (encoded in `EM`).

Comment: do you mean RSA SSA PSS is handled with EM (encoded message)?

Comment: Just use any cryptography library to generate some sample outputs. Note that PSS with a randomly generated salt is non-deterministic, so you can't test it with test vectors unless you can control the salt value.